# How I can display all imagefrom Array in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display all images in Array, I using map but it didn't work

```
export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            gifs: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G')
        .then( response => {
            this.setState({ gifs: [...this.state.gifs, response.data.data] }); // This line is different
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);  
        })

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.gifs){
        return (
                <div className="container">
                    {this.state.gifs.map( gif =>(
                    <div className="card mt-5" style={{width: 224 + 'px'}} key={gif[0].id}>
                    <img className="card-img-top" src={gif[0].images.preview_gif.url}alt="test"></img>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h4 className="card-title">{gif[0].title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        ))}
              </div>
        );
    }
    }
}
```

I expect all images showing up
[results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3X7T.png)

And this is my Data

[My data from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTEDv.png)

[This is data from my State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkuVh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was inserting the array of gifs from the api inside the `state` array, like this `{ gifs: [[gifsarr]]}` `response.data.data` is already an array of objects so just assign them to `this.state.gifs`

An empty array will **always** return `true` if you check for `if (this.state.gifs) {}` you will have to check if the `length` is > 0

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      gifs: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=nNwaquW24K8gLDmrxGTmawppQoTkXxLQ&tag=&rating=G"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ gifs: response.data.data }); // This line is different
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.gifs.length) return null;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {/* gif is an object and not an array you dont need to access it by index */}
        {this.state.gifs.map(gif => (
          <div className="card mt-5" style={{ width: 224 + "px" }} key={gif.id}>
            <img
              className="card-img-top"
              src={gif.images.preview_gif.url}
              alt="test"
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h4 className="card-title">{gif.title}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq3x2)

Comment: Please check at data from API, if I don't put [0] it would be returning an error

Comment: @SyahrizalSetiawan i also updated the way you access `gif` properties inside the `map` function, just copy the component from my answer

Comment: @SyahrizalSetiawan I've added a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq3x2) take a look

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it will be showing of 1st image in the array. as you have provided [0].
Please use below code and check it out.

```
<div className="container">
  {this.state.gifs.map( gif =>(
    <div className="card mt-5" style={{width: 224 + 'px'}} key={gif.id}>
      <img className="card-img-top" src={gif.url} alt="test"></img>
      <div className="card-body">
          <h4 className="card-title">{gif.title}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: it not work, TypeError: Cannot read property 'preview_gif' of undefined.
please look at data there is 0 which If I don't give[0] it would be return error

Comment: I have edited do check again. Just replace the parameter as per api

Comment: Can you provide the working code.
Or error. Or output you are getting.
Can add console.log(this.state.gifs) in render

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.gifs.map(gif => (
          <div className="card mt-5" style={{ width: 224 + "px" }} key={gif.id}>
            <img
              className="card-img-top"
              src={gif.images.preview_gif.url}
              alt="test"
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h4 className="card-title">{gif.title}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You need not worry about the else part, as when the list will be blank, none of the inner div's will get rendered. i.e. there will be an empty .container div

Answer (score 0):

How you're generating the array is a specific part of your code. You can make a Code Sandbox for us to test it.

But as far as displaying images from an array of `src's`, that's what I usually do:

**NOTE:** When you map an array, React will demand a `key` property on each element of the resulting array. You can use the `index` number, as long as you're not planning on re-ordering the items. If you do, you need some sort of unique ID to use as a `key`.

```js
function App() {
  
  const imagesArray = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Thumbup.jpg",
    "https://sociorocketnewsen.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/thumb-top1.jpg?w=640",
    "https://news.power102fm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/thumbs-up-.jpg"
  ];
  
  const imageItems = imagesArray.map((image,index) => 
    <div key={index} className="imageContainer">
      <img src={image} className="image"/>
    </div>
  );
  
  return(
     <React.Fragment>
      {imageItems}
     </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```